# Cannot select a default email attribute in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I created a data extension from an ETL that pushes in contacts associated with a signup session on our platform.

This data extension has a data relationship through the data designer.

When I go to set up the default email attribute, which appears as a field in the data extension, I cannot select anything there.

The contact_id on the data extension has a relation to the subscriber key and the data extension is testable and sendable.

I must be missing something on the configuration of this.

Comment: Does your email field in the DE use the data type 'EmailAddress'?

Comment: Yes, it uses the type EmailAddress.

Comment: No...it doesn't.  Sheesh.  My bad.  I had to rebuild this data extension due to a change in the ETL I configured this afternoon.  I must have either missed it or the UI gets jumpy sometimes.   Looks like I just needed someone to call out the elephant in the room.  Throw that in the answer bucket for some reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes in an Attribute Set (that is, a Data Extension with a linked relationship to the Contact in your Contact Model) need to have an EmailAddress data type in order to be selected when using 'Use email attribute from Contacts' in your Journey Settings.